# mathdesign vs. droidsans: No bold sans in TL13

Tags: fonts, bold, mathdesign

The example below works perfectly with TeX Live 2012
[image: TL 12]
but in TL 13 the sans bold version is missing.
[image: TL 13]

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/fds/mb/n' undefined
                    using `T1/fds/m/n' instead on input line 8.
```

Commenting `mathdesign` makes the bold version appear. The loading order makes no difference.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[defaultsans,scale=0.85]{droidsans}
\RequirePackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
Text\sffamily\bfseries Bold
\end{document}
```

I guess it has something to do with the version of `mathdesign`, which was upgraded from v1.55 to v2.31 in the meantime. But I couldn’t find a change log to investigate further. According to the `\filelist` the other packages didn’t change. Both distributions are as up to date as possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `mathdesign` package has `\renewcommand\bfdefault{mb}` (in `mdugm.sty`, the file that is loaded with Garamond) to set the default bold font to "medium bold", which is not defined for the Droid fonts, therefore falling back to the normal weight.

But you can safely set the bold font back to LaTeX's default, since `mathdesign` also knows the substitution rule `bx` `->` `mb`. So with:

```
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bx}
```

(after loading `mathdesign`) you will get bold fonts for both Droid and Garamond.

Comment: Thanks. I searched for `bf` in `mathdesign.sty` because presumed something like this but it must be set in a definition file … It’s silly that there’s no change log for `mathdesign` (at least _I_ didn’t found it) …